# How to download a wav file from a web location to local server directory using PHP script

Tags: php

I would like to download this [.WAV file](http://www.kookoo.in/recordings/sandeepeecs/useraudiofile2277.wav)  to my webdirectory

> /home/usename/savewavfiles/

I need a PHP script to perform this task or any sample code or tutorial would be a great help.

thanks,
sandeep

Answer (score 2):

If you have curl enabled:

```
<?php
/*
This is usefull when you are downloading big files, as it
will prevent time out of the script :
*/
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('display_errors',true);//Just in case we get some errors, let us know....

$fp = fopen (dirname(__FILE__) . '/my.way', 'w+');//This is the file where we save the information
$ch = curl_init('http://www.kookoo.in/recordings/sandeepeecs/useraudiofile2277.wav');//Here is the file we are downloading
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 50);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
?>
```

[Source](http://www.webdigity.com/index.php?action=tutorial;code=45)

Comment: hey which is the best solution out of the two, my files wont be more than 5 MB of size. and any specif reason

Comment: Well as stated both are OK, but I prefer curl - it is faster. Take a look at this benchmark: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/555523/file-get-contents-vs-curl-what-has-better-performance

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like this:

```
$link = 'http://remote.server.com/directory/sound_file.wav';
$my_dir = '/home/usename/savewavfiles/';

// get contents of the remote file
$remote_file = file_get_contents($link);

// create local file
$handle = fopen($mydir . basename($link), 'w');

// fill the local file with the contents from the remote server
fwrite($handle, $remote_file);

// close the local file
fclose($handle);
```

you can also use linux's `wget`:

```
$link = 'http://remote.server.com/directory/sound_file.wav';
shell_exec('wget '. $link);
```

Comment: which one will be better of these two BTW i have curl enabled and my files wont be more than 5 MB

Comment: they both are good solutions, personally I like `file_get_contents`, but there's no particular reason :)

Answer (score 0):

That's easy for small ( < memory) files:

```
file_put_contents(
    'localfile.wav',
    file_get_contents('http://example.org/remotefile.wav')
);
```